# Why do nurses need special watches?

Tags: time-of-day, hospital, nursing

While looking for watches, I came in contact with the concept of a "nurse watch". This seems to be a whole "thing". A certain kind of watch appears to be called a "nurse watch", presumably because it is mostly used by nurses.

But why? Why do nurses need a special kind of watch? Why not just a wristwatch or indeed any kind of time-keeping unit that they put in their pocket? Why a special "category" dedicated specifically for this profession?

Comment: Questions on Medical Sciences are required to show prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. At the very least, please provide a link to one of the products you're talking about.

Comment: My mother was a nurse and had a pendant watch that pinned to her blouse. She could tip it up to see the face. Wrist watches are likely a problem with rubber gloves and hand washing.

Comment: I’ve never heard of a nurses watch, nor have I heard of a doctor’s watch. Any watch with a second hand should suffice. Everything else is bells and whistles.

Comment: I think the watch industry's marketing plans have succeeded. ;-)